# How do I open the attachment txt file from server response using perl?

Tags: perl, attachment, mime, content-disposition

sorry if, this question seems simple, but I have been searching for a while now and have not found an answer that can be applied to my situation.

I wrote a little perl script that uploads a file to a server. This server responds with a:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

It wasn't until I read the response as string:

```
print $res->as_string, "\n";
```

that I saw that the server seemed to have attached his response in a file:

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.txt

**How do I get to the content of this .txt file using perl?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Disposition` header in the HTTP response is mainly a hint for browsers to save the file as download named `filename.txt`. You can access the file just like the content of every other HTTP response:

```
$res->content
```

or

```
$res->decoded_content
```

<sub>I assume you use `LWP::UserAgent`.</sub>

Comment: so the filename is just a header and not an actual attachment? hmmm, as I get an empty string. I can then conclude that the response is indeed empty?

Comment: Yes, this means that the response is empty. Another indication of an empty response body would be a `Content-Length` header of 0, if present.

Comment: ah, also a useful hint. Thank you nwellndof